# calculating lat long value of misr data in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am having problem in calculating lat lon value in MISR as eos2dump is not dumping the value even after executing from command prompt as shown in the examples in your site but still there is no data in output file.

Comment: Could you please describe more in details your problem and, possibly, post your code?

Comment: this command was used to generate lat and lon in text file.
$eos2dump -c1 MISR_AM1_AS_AEROSOL_P148_O076961_F12_0022.hdf > lat_MISR_AM1_AS_AEROSOL_P148_O076961_F12_0022.output
$eos2dump -c2 MISR_AM1_AS_AEROSOL_P148_O076961_F12_0022.hdf > lon_MISR_AM1_AS_AEROSOL_P148_O076961_F12_0022.output 
and after opening it it is showing "No such file or directory exists"

Comment: Please put the command into your question, it is difficult to read in a comment. Is that the complete error message? In which directory are the files located?